# Getting org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 using com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-types

I'm attempting to use this library for persisting JSON with JPA & Hibernate:

https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types

I am following (in every meaningful detail) the examples from this article:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/

Here is my (Gradle) dependency:

```
compile 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-5:2.2.2'
```

And here is the source of my entity class:

```
package org.apereo.portal.fbms.data;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FBMS_FORM")
@TypeDef(
        name = "json",
        typeClass = JsonStringType.class
)
public class FormEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String fname; // TODO:  Regex-based validator

    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "SCHEMA", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "json")
    private JsonNode schema;

    @Column(name = "METADATA")
    @Type(type = "json")
    private JsonNode metadata;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Additional getters and setters omitted for brevity...

}
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1688) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
        at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlAlterStrings(Table.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.migrateTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384) ~[spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

In case it's helpful...

- I haven't included info on RDBMS platform or JDBC driver;  that's intentional -- the solution needs to be database platform-independent.
- I will be using spring-data-jpa with this entity.

Answer (score 2):

Way to solve this, in my case, was adding custom hibernate dialect. [This](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/) resource might be helpful. Create custom dialect class:

```
// CustomPostgreSQLDialect.java
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

and will need to register your custom dialect in properties

```
# application.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: "com.test.CustomPostgreSQLDialect"
```

and if you need to provide the custom `CustomPostgreSQLDialect` via the `hibernate.dialect` configuration property:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.dialect"
    value="com.test.CustomPostgreSQLDialect"
/>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and went for your solution, but with no joy. See second approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371808/springbootkotlinpostgres-and-jsonb-org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialec?noredirect=1#comment108569814_61371808 Did you add addScalar as shown above?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what action triggers this exception, you have different ways to fix it.

In your case, you got the issue during bootstrap, meaning the Hibernate Dialect did not have a mapping for the `1111` JDBC column type, which stands for `Types.OTHER`. So, you need to register it using the current Dialect, like this:

```
public class PostgreSQL95JsonDialect
        extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public PostgreSQL95JsonDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(
            Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName()
        );
    }
}
```

Ans use the custom Hibernate Dialect:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.dialect"
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.type.json.PostgreSQL95JsonDialect"
/>
```

If you get this exception when executing SQL native queries, then you need to pass the type via `addScalar`:

```
JsonNode properties = (JsonNode) entityManager
.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT properties " +
    "FROM book " +
    "WHERE isbn = :isbn")
.setParameter("isbn", "978-9730228236")
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
.addScalar("properties", JsonNodeBinaryType.INSTANCE)
.getSingleResult();

assertEquals(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence",
    properties.get("title").asText()
);
```

For more details about this topic, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/) as well.

Comment: Best answer from the DB champ :) Just an addition if you're using Spring boot then the `hibernate.dialect` can be also set by the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` property in the `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a bug in Vlad's library - when I'd changed column definition from `json` to `text` (`@Column(columnDefinition = "text")`) then all worked fine.

But I think you should [use `jsonb`](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/) instead of `json`. With 'jsonb' all works as expected:

```
@Column(name = "METADATA", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@Type(type = "jsonb")
private JsonNode metadata;
```

See my demo: [sb-hibernate-types-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-hibernate-types-demo)

**UPDATED**

A kind of workaround - with custom Hibernate dialect, where I've registered column type `clob` for code `Types.OTHER` (1111), all works fine. Tested on [H2](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-hibernate-types-demo/tree/h2) and [HSQLD](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-hibernate-types-demo/tree/hsqldb) databases.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I don't understand why you'd need to specify both `columnDefinition` and `@Type`... but (in any case) your suggestion gives me "SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks privilege: JSONB"

Comment: To use `jsonb` you should add it to `@TypeDefs` annotation: '@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)` (did you see/run my demo?).  I used `columnDefinition` to explicitly define the type of the column.

Comment: Still no luck.  I *am* including `@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)`;  with `columnDefinition = "jsonb"` I get `SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks privilege: JSONB`;  without `columnDefinition = "jsonb"` I get `MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`.  I looked at your example -- have you ever run it with HSQLDB?  (I'm hoping to make some time to do so.)

Comment: I notice your JDBC driver is hard-coded to PostgreSQL:  https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-hibernate-types-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L6

Comment: "have you ever run it with HSQLDB?" No. Does HSQLDB [supports](https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/feature-requests/332/) `jsonb`?

Comment: I have no idea if HSQL supports jsonb.  I need a way to store JSON in (ideally) any relational database with a working Hibernate dialect.  (That's why the original question says "I haven't included info on RDBMS platform or JDBC driver; that's intentional -- the solution needs to be database platform-independent.")  I would love to have, but don't strictly need fancy features for JSON (e.g. query inside), I just need to save and retrieve decent-size documents in a column.