# SpringBoot+Kotlin+Postgres and JSONB: "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have been consulting a number of approaches/posts/stackoverflow questions in order to deal with the following error (full stack trace) when running a Kotlin/SpringBoot application:

```
2020-04-22 18:33:56.823 ERROR 46345 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2118910070
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at app.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2118910070
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2118910070
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

The issue lies in mapping the PostgreSQL’s JSONB data type with Hibernate.

The 2 approaches I have extensively tried and debugged are the following:

1. Implementing a Custom Hibernate Mapping and creating a custom UserType for JSONB. References: [here](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/postgresqls-jsonb-type-mapping-using-hibernate/), [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967180/how-to-create-custom-jsonb-mapper-for-postgresql-and-hibernate-in-kotlin) and [here](https://github.com/thjanssen/HibernateJSONBSupport/tree/master/PostgresJSONB/src/main/java/org/thoughts/on/java/model)
2. Use Hibernate types. References are [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/), [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/) and [here](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence)

I have attempted profusely at both, but with no luck whatsoever and I am keen to understand where I am going wrong and what I have been missing.

**Approach 1**

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "JsonUserType", typeClass = JsonUserType::class)
@Table(name = "entity")
data class MyEntity(
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val id: UUID,
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val type: Type,
  @Type(type = "JsonUserType")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  var event_data: Event
) : SomeEntity<UUID>(), SomeOtherStuff {
  override fun getName(): String {
    return id
  }
}
 
 
enum class Type(val value: String) {
  TYPE1("Type1"),
  TYPE2("Type2")
}
```

My PoJO:

```
data class Event(
  val someContent: String,
  val someBoolean: Boolean
) : Serializable { //equals, hashcode etc are omitted }
```

My Custom Hibernate dialect:

```
class CustomPostgreSQLDialect : PostgreSQL95Dialect {
  constructor() : super() {
    this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb")
  }
}
```

My custom type (abstract class)

```
abstract class JsonDataUserType : UserType {

  override fun sqlTypes(): IntArray? {
    return intArrayOf(Types.JAVA_OBJECT)
  }

  override fun equals(value1: Any?, value2: Any?): Boolean {
    return value1 == value2
  }

  override fun hashCode(value1: Any?): Int {
    return value1!!.hashCode()
  }

  override fun assemble(value1: Serializable?, value2: Any?): Any {
    return deepCopy(value1)
  }

  override fun disassemble(value1: Any?): Serializable {
    return deepCopy(value1) as Serializable
  }

  override fun deepCopy(p0: Any?): Any {
    return try {
      val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
      val oos = ObjectOutputStream(bos)
      oos.writeObject(p0)
      oos.flush()
      oos.close()
      bos.close()
      val bais = ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray())
      ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject()
    } catch (ex: ClassNotFoundException) {
      throw HibernateException(ex)
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
      throw HibernateException(ex)
    }
  }

  override fun replace(p0: Any?, p1: Any?, p2: Any?): Any {
    return deepCopy(p0)
  }

  override fun nullSafeSet(p0: PreparedStatement?, p1: Any?, p2: Int, p3: SharedSessionContractImplementor?) {
    if (p1 == null) {
      p0?.setNull(p2, Types.OTHER)
      return
    }
    try {
      val mapper = ObjectMapper()
      val w = StringWriter()
      mapper.writeValue(w, p1)
      w.flush()
      p0?.setObject(p2, w.toString(), Types.OTHER)
    } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
      throw RuntimeException("Failed to convert Jsonb to String: " + ex.message, ex)
    }
  }
  override fun nullSafeGet(p0: ResultSet?, p1: Array<out String>?, p2: SharedSessionContractImplementor?, p3: Any?): Any {
    val cellContent = p0?.getString(p1?.get(0))
    return try {
      val mapper = ObjectMapper()
      mapper.readValue(cellContent?.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")), returnedClass())
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      throw RuntimeException("Failed to convert String to Jsonb: " + ex.message, ex)
    }
  }

  override fun isMutable(): Boolean {
    return true
  }

}
```

Such class was taken from this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967180/how-to-create-custom-jsonb-mapper-for-postgresql-and-hibernate-in-kotlin)

My concrete class:

```
class JsonType : JsonDataUserType() {
    override fun returnedClass(): Class<Event> {
      return Event::class.java
    }
}
```

My application.yml jpa hibernate properties

```
jpa.properties.database.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.myapp.util.CustomPostgreSQLDialect
```

**Approach 2**

Hibernate properties are exactly the same as well as the PoJo class, no custom mapper is included.

Entity

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(
  name = "jsonb",
  typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class
)
@Table(name = "entity")
data class MyEntity(
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val id: UUID,
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val type: Type,
  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  var event_data: Event
) : SomeEntity<UUID>(), SomeOtherStuff {
  override fun getName(): String {
    return id
  }
}
  
  
enum class Type(val value: String) {
  TYPE1("Type1"),
  TYPE2("Type2")
}
```

Custom Dialect (using hibernate types):

```
class CustomPostgreSQLDialect : PostgreSQL95Dialect {
  constructor() : super() {
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType::class.java.name)
  }
}
```

Please note that I also tried using only:

```
this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, "jsonb")
```

as well as having all this in my entity or the base entity it extended from (no change for that matter):

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb-node", typeClass = JsonNodeBinaryType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "json-node", typeClass = JsonNodeStringType.class),
})
```

Is there anything evidently wrong I am doing in both approaches? I cannot get it working and, not sure if in any way relevant, the numerical value after *No Dialect mapping for JDBC type:* is always different. I am adding this as I have seen some ids being relevant for certain categories of errors.

Can you help?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I wanted to provide more info regarding jpa, postgres and hibernate versions. I am currently working with the following:

1. postgres:10-alpine
2. PostgreSQL JDBC Driver JDBC 4.2 » 42.2.8
3. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.1.RELEASE
4. org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.8.Final

   Is there any particular versioning issues among them?

**EDIT 2**
I have been trying to successfully use hibernate-types (Approach 2 as explained above). I have made the following change according to the Postgres version (10):

```
class CustomPostgreSQLDialect : PostgreSQL10Dialect {
  constructor() : super() {
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType::class.java.name)
  }
}
```

Then in my entity I have

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
```

and

```
 @Type(type = "jsonb")
 @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
 @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 var event_data: Event
```

I have then debugged the *get* method in *TypeNames* where the error is coming from:

```
public String get(final int typeCode) throws MappingException {
        final Integer integer = Integer.valueOf( typeCode );
        final String result = defaults.get( integer );
        if ( result == null ) {
            throw new MappingException( "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: " + typeCode );
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and this is what I am getting:

```
defaults = {HashMap@12093}  size = 27
     {Integer@12124} -1 -> "text"
     {Integer@12126} 1 -> "char(1)"
     {Integer@12128} -2 -> "bytea"
     {Integer@12130} 2 -> "numeric($p, $s)"
     {Integer@12132} -3 -> "bytea"
     {Integer@12133} -4 -> "bytea"
     {Integer@12134} 4 -> "int4"
     {Integer@12136} -5 -> "int8"
     {Integer@12138} -6 -> "int2"
     {Integer@12140} 5 -> "int2"
     {Integer@12141} -7 -> "bool"
     {Integer@12143} 6 -> "float4"
     {Integer@12145} 7 -> "real"
     {Integer@12147} 8 -> "float8"
     {Integer@12149} -9 -> "nvarchar($l)"
     {Integer@12151} 12 -> "varchar($l)"
     {Integer@12153} -15 -> "nchar($l)"
     {Integer@12155} -16 -> "nvarchar($l)"
     {Integer@12156} 16 -> "boolean"
     {Integer@12158} 2000 -> "json"
     {Integer@12160} 2004 -> "oid"
     {Integer@12162} 2005 -> "text"
     {Integer@12163} 1111 -> "uuid"
     {Integer@12165} 91 -> "date"
     {Integer@12167} 2011 -> "nclob"
     {Integer@12169} 92 -> "time"
     {Integer@12171} 93 -> "timestamp"
```

No *jsonb* can be found and when I debug my custom dialect, I am getting the following:

```
{Integer@10846} 1111 -> "com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType"
 key = {Integer@10846} 1111
 value = "com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType"
```

Why is that? Why am I not getting the jsonb type?

Comment: The easiest way to work with postgres's jsonb and hibernate is using the library and example shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326794/7736814

Comment: Sorry, that was one of the many resources I have used in my many many attempts and that did not work.

Comment: @peterzinho16 I am following the approach from the cited sourced (meaning I am not creating a custom UserType, dropped that approach), but still the same issue. I have updated my post with some additional debugging. Any idea why this is still not working? Thanks

Comment: @paranza Can you add some repo with a simple Spring Boot app, so I can play with code? It is very hard to follow so many code snippets.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, I will come back to you as soon as possible with a small demo

Comment: Hey @dmytro-chasovskyi, I updated with an answer

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi I have put together a very minimal working project [here](https://github.com/ilacorda/demo). It is very basic, I need to add a README etc, but it is as close as it gets (the Base Entity from which my Entity extends is a bit different). I am not sure if that gives a better insight, I am still wondering in the dark.

Comment: Btw I opened a bounty attached to this SO question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose my solution in a [pull-request](https://github.com/ilacorda/demo/pull/1)

The idea is to change Entity to:

```
import com.example.demo.pojo.SamplePojo
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
@TypeDefs(
        TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
)
data class SampleEntity (
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long?,
    val name: String?,

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    var data: Map<String, Any>?
) {

    /**
     * Dependently on use-case this can be done differently:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873995/how-to-create-empty-constructor-for-data-class-in-kotlin-android
     */
    constructor(): this(null, null, null)
}
```

1. Each entity should either have a default constructor or have defaults for all its parameters
2. Instead of saving POJO, save as `Map<String, Any>` type

Since we have a full-control what will be in POJO in business logic the only missing piece will be to convert POJO to Map and Map to POJO

SamplePojo implementation

```
data class SamplePojo(
        val payload: String,
        val flag: Boolean
)  {
    constructor(map: Map<String, Any>) : this(map["payload"] as String, map["flag"] as Boolean)

    fun toMap() : Map<String, Any> {
        return mapOf("payload" to payload, "flag" to flag)
    }
}
```

This is rather a workaround but it allows us to work with any depth-level structures.

P.S. I noticed that you use `Serializer` and redefined `equals, toString, hashCode`. You don't need this if using [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

**UPDATE:**

If you need a more flexible structure than `Map<String, Any>`, you can use `JsonNode`. [Code example](https://github.com/ilacorda/demo/pull/1/commits/78de96b32287c64dffe482cf3c0fc703f00be9d6)

Entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
@TypeDefs(
        TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
)
data class SampleJsonNodeEntity (
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        val id: Long?,
        val name: String?,

        @Type(type = "jsonb")
        @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
        var data: JsonNode?
) {

    /**
     * Dependently on use-case this can be done differently:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873995/how-to-create-empty-constructor-for-data-class-in-kotlin-android
     */
    constructor(): this(null, null, null)
}
```

Change Entity in Repository:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.SampleJsonNodeEntity
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

interface SampleJsonNodeRepository: JpaRepository<SampleJsonNodeEntity, Long> {
}
```

Tests for both approaches:

```
import com.example.demo.DbTestInitializer
import com.example.demo.entity.SampleJsonNodeEntity
import com.example.demo.entity.SampleMapEntity
import com.example.demo.pojo.SamplePojo
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals
import junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner


@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [DbTestInitializer::class])
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class SampleRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var sampleMapRepository: SampleMapRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var sampleJsonNodeRepository: SampleJsonNodeRepository

    lateinit var dto: SamplePojo
    lateinit var mapEntity: SampleMapEntity
    lateinit var jsonNodeEntity: SampleJsonNodeEntity

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        dto = SamplePojo("Test", true)
        mapEntity = SampleMapEntity(null,
                "POJO1",
                dto.toMap()
        )

        jsonNodeEntity = SampleJsonNodeEntity(null,
            "POJO2",
                jacksonObjectMapper().valueToTree(dto)
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun createMapPojo() {
        val id = sampleMapRepository.save(mapEntity).id!!
        assertNotNull(sampleMapRepository.getOne(id))
        assertEquals(sampleMapRepository.getOne(id).data?.let { SamplePojo(it) }, dto)
    }

    @Test
    fun createJsonNodePojo() {
        val id = sampleJsonNodeRepository.save(jsonNodeEntity).id!!
        assertNotNull(sampleJsonNodeRepository.getOne(id))
        assertEquals(jacksonObjectMapper().treeToValue(sampleJsonNodeRepository.getOne(id).data, SamplePojo::class.java), dto)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for putting some work on this, much appreciated. I have quickly implemented the changes (with no tests yet) and I am stuck with the very same issue. Before writing some tests, i have a few questions. Are we removing the custom dialect? I have not posted my dto and the converter, but shall I have the toMap method there?

Comment: A custom dialect should remain. Yes, basically you have either methods that convert dto to map and vice versa map to dto, I showed possible solution in SamplePojo. Also, one of the problems that I saw in your code, you use custom serializer, try for now keep objects as stupid as possible, to make sure that it's Hibernate's fallacy. Btw, I tested code in Java 11 and Postgres 11. If nothing works for you, start from my code sample because it works both as a stand-alone run and tests.

Comment: Hi, while your code works as expected, indeed, unfortunately my application does not deal well with Any in the Map. I am not sure how to deal with it. Any idea?

Comment: Don't you want to move into a separate discussion under PR I submitted, so I can see where the problem lays and you can submit code samples and details? I believe Map issue is  out of scope for this discussion.

Comment: I agree, I have put a comment in your PR. Will update my demo later, thank you for all your work, although my actual application is a bit more convoluted, I think your solution deserves the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Extending with an example, sorry I know I am a bit late

in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I have my entity named Day:

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;

@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
@Data
@Entity
public class Day {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "DayId")
   private Integer id;
   private Integer day;
   private Integer month;
   private Integer year;

   @Type(type = "jsonb")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
   private List<Activity> activities;

   @Type(type = "jsonb")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
   private Notification notification;

}
```

Activity and Notification JSONB's class:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Activity implements Serializable {

   private String name;
   private String emoji;
   private Integer durationInSeconds;
   private Boolean highPriority;

   public Activity (){}
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Notification implements Serializable {

    private String email;
    private String mobile;

    public Notification (){}
}
```

Our repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DayRepository extends CrudRepository<Day, Integer> {

}
```

Our service:

```
public interface DayService{
    Day saveArbitraryDay();
}

@Service
@Transactional
public DayServiceImpl implements DayService{

    private DayRepository repository;

    public DayServiceImpl(DayRepository repository){
         this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Day saveArbitraryDay(){
         Day day = new Day();
         day.setDay(16);
         day.setMonth(04);
         day.setYear(1991);

         //Set the jsonb objects
         //You can use custom constructors whatever
         Notification notification = new Notification();
         notification.setEmail("contoso@hotmail.com");
         day.setNotification(notification);

         //Now putting activities
         List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();

         Activity actOne = new Activity();
         actOne.setName("Breakfast");
         actOne.setEmoji("");
         actOne.setDurationInSeconds(9000);
         actOne.setHighPriority(true);

         Activity actTwo = new Activity();
         actTwo.setName("Shopping");
         actTwo.setEmoji("");

         activities.add(actOne);
         activities.add(actTwo);

         day.setActivities(activities)

         return repository.save(day);
    }
}
```

And that is pretty much I think, in case you wanna digging more into types with hibernate check out this [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)